# Trying to deploy printer settings via intune app deployment

Tags: powershell, intune

Im currently trying to deploy specific Settings for a Printer via Intune (never done this b4). I found out that you can Ex- and Import Printer Settings with the "printui.exe" tool coming with Windows. I used the tool to create a .dat file of the Printer-settings and tested the Import locally in Powershell (worked perfectly).

Export:
Printui.exe /Ss /n “Universal Printer” /a “c:\x\config.dat”

Import:
Printui.exe /Sr /n “Universal Printer” /a “config.dat”

This alone is working perfectly without any Issues. Now; I want to do this via Intune. My way to go is the following:

I created a .ps1 file, that does the exact same thing and executes the same command as above.
Then I packaged the .dat file and the ps1 file into an .intunewin file and deployed it. For some reason I just cant get it to work that way. I tried to add a line in the Script to save the .dat file locally and use that for the Import of the settings, still not the wanted result. For some reason, no matter what I try, I cant import the settings when deploying with Intune. I tried to import the Settings manually, same .dat file, same ps script and same way to call the ps script*, still didnt work.

Im not entirely sure on how .intunewin files work and what is needed for the Printui.exe to work properly, but the Command itself doesnt give any feedback either. I cant tell if the import just didnt work or if it went trough and the Problem is somewhere else.

*Command to Call the Script (used in Intune deployment)
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file Install-Settings.ps1

Im pretty new to Intune and im still learning, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the script? Thanks

Comment: Here is a doc that can help you with deploying win32 / LOB apps to intune. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/apps-win32-add

Comment: @alexzelaya Good Morning and excuse my late Reply. Following would be my Code; 

New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path C:\Windows\Temp\PowerShell_transcript
Start-Transcript -OutputDirectory C:\Windows\Temp\PowerShell_transcript
Copy-Item ".\config.dat" -Destination "C:\Windows\Temp\PowerShell_transcript"
Printui.exe /Sr /n "Universal Printer" /a "C:\Windows\Temp\PowerShell_transcript\config.dat"

Quick Note; I found out that the Script couldnt find the .dat file if I would give the Script the direct path in the Intunewin file. But If I copy it onto the Local drive that Problem is solved.

Comment: The Folder which is created by the first Line is also used to check if the "App" is already installed on this Computer. Im pretty sure that the code isnt the cause, because it works when I try to apply the settings manually from a local Powershell window with the same exact code. The Powershell Transcript also shows that the Code went trough without any Error.